# Why new saved item has 0 in id field?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Making job with new item created new saved item has 0 in id field when I try to pass this item in event.

Model item is made without autoincrement field (this id is passed from other app and must be saved):

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedSmallInteger('id')->primary();
    $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
});
```

Job Code:

```
class RMQItemCreated implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private array $data ;
    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        $item = Item::create(['id' => $this->data['id'], 'active' => true]);
        $item->load('itemLikedCounts'); // load related models

       ItemCreatedEvent::dispatch($item);
    }
```

I check in db and see that new item row was added with valid id.
But checking content of a item model in ItemCreatedEvent I see that id === 0

In model app/Models/Item.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'items';
//    protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // if to uncomment this - the same results
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'active'];
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }


    public function itemLikedCounts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\ItemLikedCount::class);
    }

}
```

I tried to load relation itemLikedCounts, but it did not help...

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.41",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried adding $item->refresh() before sending it to ItemCreatedEvent ? $item->load will not working if item id it self is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your key is not auto-incrementing you have to specify that in the model:

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'items';
    public $incrementing = false; // here

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'active'];
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }


    public function itemLikedCounts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\ItemLikedCount::class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare that your id is not incrementing in your model:

```php
public $incrementing = false;
```

Instead of

```php
$item = Item::create(['id' => $this->data['id'], 'active' => true]);
```

Try this:

```php
$item = new Item();
$item->id = $this->data['id'];
$item->active = true;
$item->save();
```

This should pass the ID to event!